# Friend function in-class definition only allowed in non-local class definitions. What does it mean?

Tags: c++, friend

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) (see point 2 description) I read that a friend function in-class definition is only allowed in *non-local* class definition.

What does that mean?

Comment: Your question is unclear and malformed. Links are not a substitute for content.

Comment: I think is very precise and self-contained, the link is not really necessary to understand the question. Indeed I have received the answer I was after in less than 1 minute.

Comment: The answers you got are all explaining what a local class is - that's not what your question asks. It's nice that you got the answer you needed, but the question is still malformed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-local class is a class that's not local.

A local class is a class defined in a function - see paragraph "Local classes" [on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class)

"Friend function in-class definition" refers to ability to declare and define a non-member function inside a class, which is a friend of the class it's enclosed in.

```
class a_class
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const a_class& x)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Received 3 almost equivalent answers. I'm simply accepting the first one.

Answer (score 3):

A non-local class definition is a definition that is not defined in other class' body or it not embedded in a function body.

So basically you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct NonLocal
{
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const NonLocal& l)
  {
    os << l.x;
    return os;
  }

private:
  int x;
};

int main()
{
  NonLocal nl;
  std::cout << nl;
}
```

but you cannot do this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  struct Local
  {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Local& l) // this will fail to compile
    {
      os << l.x;
      return os;
    }

  private:
    int x;
  };

  Local l;
  std::cout << l;
}
```

From the [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Local_classes):

> A class declaration can appear in namespace scope (in which case it
> defines an ordinary class), inside another class definition (in which
> case it defines a nested class), and inside the body of a function, in
> which case it defines a **local class**. The name of such a class only
> exists within the function scope, and is not accessible outside.
>
> - A local class cannot have static members
> - Member functions of a local class have no linkage
> - Member functions of a local class have to be defined entirely inside the class body
> - Local classes other than closure types (since C++14) cannot have member templates
> - Local classes cannot have friend templates
> - A local class inside a function (including member function) can access the same names that the enclosing function can access.
> - local classes could not be used as template arguments (until C++11)

[emphasis mine]

Answer (score 2):

It means that you cannot do this:

```
void function ()
{
    class X
    {
        int a;
        friend void friend_set(X& p, int i)
        {
            p.a = i;
        }
        public:
        void member_set(int i)
        {
            a = i;
        }
    };
}
```

Local-classes are the ones defined inside a function.